# PHP SOAP response in XML - how to read it as variable

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I get response from SOAP WSDL call:

```
$client = new SoapClient($settings['address']);
$params = new stdClass();
$params->Username = $settings['username'];
$params->Password = $settings['password'];
var_dump($client->Get_Brands($params));
```

Below is response. How to actually read it in PHP? Do I need to traverse it with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or is there something like returning SOAP result into object or array?

```
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Table">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <DocumentElement xmlns="">
        <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Description>Alfa Romeo</Description>
        </Table>

        <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
            <ID>2</ID>
            <Description>Alpina</Description>
        </Table>
    </DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should pass valid WSDL definition as first argument of SoapClient().
You may also set some specific options as second argument (for example soap_version).
Normally there is no need to parse SOAP response - you should get method result of certain type.
However if SOAP response in not valid SoapClient can't recognize and parse it automatically, you may need to parse it manually using DOMDocument or SimpleXML.

Comment: What is valid WSDL definition and why I should pass it? Second argument of what and what extra is there to pass? What do you mean no need for parse? I got webservice that just returns XML-ed database row and that's the only way I can get this info, but aren't there some classes that serialize XML outputs for programmers ease?